# How to disable geolocation when travelling?

Tags: geolocation

This is probably a geolocation issue.

How can I stop websites such as `change.org` and `blogger.com` from displaying in the local language. I don't understand the local language when I'm traveling.  This is a serious hindrance, not to mention risky if one tries to use a website when unsure of the meaning of things.

Is there some sort of proxy I can use on an ad hoc basis, or even on a short time subscription basis when I am traveling?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Fedora, so in network setting I manually enter the DNS server IP address(es) of either the ISP from my home or a local Google server. This has helped me in the past loading the pages in English and not the local language.

Comment: Sorry, but can you be more specific in your answer? Your answer is rather vague and does not really answer the main part of the question.

Comment: @Hydra I've improved the answer to provide a more detailed explanation. Since the question doesn't have enough details I can't give a specific answer, therefore my answer could be applied to any platform as a generic strategy.